# Brownian motion, normal distribution (3D)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, statistics

Following a previous question, this representation that might be even more pedagogic in 3D. Based on this working example extracted from [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254484/how-to-make-a-graph-of-heteroskedasticity-with-tikz-pgf/254494#254494)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\makeatletter
   \pgfdeclareplotmark{dot}
    {%
        \fill circle [x radius=0.08, y radius=0.32];
    }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ % Define Normal Probability Function
    declare function={
normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
},
declare function={invgauss(\a,\b) = sqrt(-2*ln(\a))*cos(deg(2*pi*\b));}
]
\begin{axis}[
        %no markers,
        domain=0:12,
        zmin=0, zmax=1,
        xmin=0, xmax=3,
        samples=200,
        samples y=0,
        view={40}{30},
        axis lines=middle,
        enlarge y limits=false,
        xtick={0.5,1.5,2.5},
        xmajorgrids,
        xticklabels={},
        ytick=\empty,
        xticklabels={$t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$},
        ztick=\empty,
        xlabel=$t$, xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0,0)}, anchor=west},
        ylabel=$S_t$, ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1,0)}, anchor=south west},
        zlabel=Probability density, zlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,0,0.5)}, rotate=90, anchor=south},
        set layers, mark=cube
    ]

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.5,1.5,2.5}{
        \addplot3 [draw=none, fill=black, opacity=0.25, only marks,     mark=dot, mark layer=like plot, samples=30, domain=0.1:2.9, on layer=axis background] (#1, {1.5*(#1-0.5)+3+invgauss(rnd,rnd)*#1}, 0);
    }
    \addplot3 [samples=2, samples y=0, domain=0:3] (x, {1.5*(x-0.5)+3}, 0);
    \addplot3 [cyan!50!black, thick] (0.5, x, {normal(x, 3, 0.5)});
    \addplot3 [cyan!50!black, thick] (1.5, x, {normal(x, 4.5, 1)});
    \addplot3 [cyan!50!black, thick] (2.5, x, {normal(x, 6, 1.5)});

    \pgfplotsextra{
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
            \draw [gray, on layer=axis background] 
            (0.5, 3, 0) -- (0.5, 3, {normal(0,0,0.5)}) (0.5,0,0) -- (0.5,12,0)
            (1.5, 4.5, 0) -- (1.5, 4.5, {normal(0,0,1)}) (1.5,0,0) -- (1.5,12,0)
            (2.5, 6, 0) -- (2.5, 6, {normal(0,0,1.5)}) (2.5,0,0) -- (2.5,12,0);

        \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can we simulate the paths of a given number of brownian motions as in great Marmot's solution [brownian-motion-and-rotated-normal-distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468312/brownian-motion-and-rotated-normal-distribution) and show the dynamic of the normal distribution "flattening" and spreading over time, but in 3D ?

The brownian motions would be on the bottom plane whereas the normal density would be represented in the third dimension
[image]

[image]

Comment: Source code updated !
@marmot, your dynamic version in 2D was already breathtaking. I just wonder how you would adapt it to a  3D prospective. 
No need to have the straight line attached, but maybe in the spirit of the example here, see how the path "impact" (as here with the big dots) is distributed from one time to another.
Am sketching something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a slightly advanced proposal, taking into account your comments.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} % does intersections as well
\makeatletter
        \pgfdeclareplotmark{dot}
        {%
            \fill circle [x radius=0.08, y radius=0.32];
        }%
\makeatother
\newcommand{\CreateRandomWalkTable}[4]{%
\xdef#4{(0,0,0)}
\xdef\oldy{2.25}
\foreach \X in {1,...,#1}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{#2*\X}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\oldy+1.5*#2+rand*#3}
\xdef#4{#4 (\myx,\myy,0)}
\xdef\oldy{\myy}
}}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\CreateRandomWalkTable{140}{0.02}{0.2}{\mytabone}
\pgfmathsetseed{11}
\CreateRandomWalkTable{140}{0.02}{0.2}{\mytabtwo}
\pgfmathsetseed{17}
\CreateRandomWalkTable{140}{0.02}{0.2}{\mytabthree}
\pgfmathsetseed{32}
\CreateRandomWalkTable{140}{0.02}{0.2}{\mytabfour}

\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0.5,0.6,...,2.5}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[ % Define Normal Probability Function
declare function={
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        },
    declare function={invgauss(\a,\b) = sqrt(-2*ln(\a))*cos(deg(2*pi*\b));}
       ]
\path[use as bounding box] (-0.5,-1) rectangle (6,5); % for animation
\begin{axis}[
    %no markers,
    domain=0:12,
    zmin=0, zmax=1,
    xmin=0, xmax=3,
    samples=200,
   samples y=0,
    view={40}{30},
    axis lines=middle,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    xtick={0.5,1.5,2.5},
    xmajorgrids,
    xticklabels={},
    ytick=\empty,
    xticklabels={$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$},
    ztick=\empty,
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0,0)}, anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1,0)}, anchor=south west},
    zlabel=Probability density, zlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,0,0.5)}, rotate=90, anchor=south},
    set layers,% mark=cube
  ]

\addplot3 [samples=2, samples y=0, domain=0:3] (x, {1.5*(x-0.5)+3}, 0);

\addplot3 [draw=none, fill=black, opacity=0.25, only marks, mark=dot, mark
layer=like plot, samples=30, domain=0.1:2.9, on layer=axis background,overlay] (\X, {1.5*(\X-0.5)+3+invgauss(rnd,rnd)*\X}, 0);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0,0) -- (\X,0,0)  -- (\X,12,0) -- (0,12,0) -- cycle;
\draw[red,no marks,name path=rp1] plot coordinates {\mytabone};
\draw[red,no marks,name path=rp2] plot coordinates {\mytabtwo};
\draw[red,no marks,name path=rp3] plot coordinates {\mytabthree};
\draw[red,no marks,name path=rp4] plot coordinates {\mytabfour};
\end{scope}
\draw [gray, on layer=axis background] (\X, 2.25+1.5*\X, 0) -- 
(\X, 2.25+1.5*\X, {normal(0,0,0.5*\X+0.25)});
\draw [gray, on layer=axis background,name path=vert] (\X,0,0) -- (\X,12,0);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\path[name intersections={of=vert and rp1,by={x1}},
name intersections={of=vert and rp2,by={x2}},
name intersections={of=vert and rp3,by={x3}},
name intersections={of=vert and rp4,by={x4}}];
\draw [fill=red, opacity=0.75, only marks, mark=dot] plot coordinates 
{(x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)};
\addplot3 [blue, very thick] (\X, x, {normal(x, 2.25+1.5*\X,0.5*\X+0.25)});

% \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.5,1.5,2.5}{
% \addplot3 [draw=none, fill=black, opacity=0.25, only marks, mark=dot, mark layer=like plot, samples=30, domain=0.1:2.9, on layer=axis background] (#1, {1.5*(#1-0.5)+3+invgauss(rnd,rnd)*#1}, 0);
% \addplot3 [cyan!50!black, thick] (#1, x, {normal(x, 2.25+1.5*#1, 0.5*#1+0.25)});
% }
% \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
% \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.5,1.5,2.5}{
% \draw [gray, on layer=axis background] (#1, 2.25+1.5*#1, 0) -- 
% (#1, 2.25+1.5*#1, {normal(0,0,0.5*#1+0.25)})
%  (#1,0,0) -- (#1,12,0);
% }
% \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\path (current axis.south east) -- ++ (0.4,-0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you increase the number of steps

```
\foreach \X in {0.5,0.525,...,2.5}
```

and convert with [see here for more info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/121799)

convert -density 300 -delay 12 -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf ani.gif

you get a smoother result:

[image]

Group plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} % does intersections as well
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\makeatletter
        \pgfdeclareplotmark{dot}
        {%
            \fill circle [x radius=0.08, y radius=0.32];
        }%
\makeatother
\newcommand{\CreateRandomWalkTable}[4]{%
\xdef#4{(0,0,0)}
\xdef\oldy{2.25}
\foreach \X in {1,...,#1}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{#2*\X}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\oldy+1.5*#2+rand*#3}
\xdef#4{#4 (\myx,\myy,0)}
\xdef\oldy{\myy}
}}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\CreateRandomWalkTable{140}{0.02}{0.2}{\mytabone}
\pgfmathsetseed{11}
\CreateRandomWalkTable{140}{0.02}{0.2}{\mytabtwo}
\pgfmathsetseed{17}
\CreateRandomWalkTable{140}{0.02}{0.2}{\mytabthree}
\pgfmathsetseed{32}
\CreateRandomWalkTable{140}{0.02}{0.2}{\mytabfour}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ % Define Normal Probability Function
declare function={
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        },
    declare function={invgauss(\a,\b) = sqrt(-2*ln(\a))*cos(deg(2*pi*\b));}
       ]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 3},height=6cm,width=6cm,
    %no markers,
    domain=0:12,
    zmin=0, zmax=1,
    xmin=0, xmax=3,
    samples=200,
    samples y=0,
    view={40}{30},
    axis lines=middle,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    xtick={0.5,1.5,2.5},
    xmajorgrids,
    xticklabels={},
    ytick=\empty,
    xticklabels={$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$},
    ztick=\empty,
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0,0)}, anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1,0)}, anchor=south west},
    zlabel=Probability density, zlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,0,0.5)}, rotate=90, anchor=south},
    set layers
  ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.5,0.9,1.3,1.7,2.1,2.5}
{\nextgroupplot[]
  \addplot3 [samples=2, samples y=0, domain=0:3] (x, {1.5*(x-0.5)+3}, 0);

  \addplot3 [draw=none, fill=black, opacity=0.25, only marks, mark=dot, mark
  layer=like plot, samples=30, domain=0.1:2.9, on layer=axis background,overlay]
  (#1, {1.5*(#1-0.5)+3+invgauss(rnd,rnd)*#1}, 0);

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
  \begin{scope}
  \clip (0,0,0) -- (#1,0,0)  -- (#1,12,0) -- (0,12,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,no marks,name path=rp1] plot coordinates {\mytabone};
  \draw[red,no marks,name path=rp2] plot coordinates {\mytabtwo};
  \draw[red,no marks,name path=rp3] plot coordinates {\mytabthree};
  \draw[red,no marks,name path=rp4] plot coordinates {\mytabfour};
  \end{scope}
  \draw [gray, on layer=axis background] (#1, 2.25+1.5*#1, 0) -- 
  (#1, 2.25+1.5*#1, {normal(0,0,0.5*#1+0.25)});
  \draw [gray, on layer=axis background,name path=vert] (#1,0,0) -- (#1,12,0);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \path[name intersections={of=vert and rp1,by={x1}},
  name intersections={of=vert and rp2,by={x2}},
  name intersections={of=vert and rp3,by={x3}},
  name intersections={of=vert and rp4,by={x4}}];
  \draw [fill=red, opacity=0.75, only marks, mark=dot] plot coordinates 
  {(x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)};
  \addplot3 [blue, very thick] (#1, x, {normal(x, 2.25+1.5*#1,0.5*#1+0.25)});
  }
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty !! I am going to try to adapt your code so that, as a printer (old style), the brownian in red appears at the same time the distribution moves forward in time.

Comment: marmot, thank you, it's exactly the idea I had in mind ! So powerful a graph.
Do you think it's possible to put a terminal point to show at each step where the path ends below the distribution ?
I also noticed the brownians started at 0 and not 2.5.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Sure it's possible.

Comment: Merci ! It's fantastic!! I validate your solution.

Comment: i tried to add another \foreach \Z in {0,15,...,90} on view={\Z}{30},. I get a \dimensiontoolarge error. I reused your code as 
\foreach \Z in {0,15,...,90}
{
 \foreach \X in {0.1,0.2,...,1}
 {\begin{tikzpicture}[ % Define Normal Probability Function
   declare function={normal(\x,\m,\s) 
...
Any idea why marmot ?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I don't but can you just try to run it with a truncated list like `\foreach \Z in {30} .... view={\Z}{30}`, check if that works, and if it does, try to extend the list? (Sometimes it is better to avoid values like `90` or `0` in the view and `85` or `5` is better because there are some sin and cos functions in the transformations, which can thus become singular.)

Comment: Thank you @marmot for this beautiful answer that really helped my students understanding the diffusion concept. I wonder how we could clip an extract of n images at different time in a groupplot. It's much better looking  (less white space between images) in article mode. Shall I start a new question ?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I just realized that after avoiding two standard pit falls, it is not too difficult. Nonetheless it might make sense to ask an official question for that such that things get separated.